# What's the difference between each other and one another in a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning, difference

Recently, I was reading a passage which I encountered with the following sentence:

> All things in an ecosystem are connected with **one another**.

While, If I was the author of this sentence, I would write **each other** instead of **one another**.

Which one is more appropriate or what's the difference between them?

Comment: There's no difference. The compound reciprocal pronouns "each other" and "one another" are semantically equivalent.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

With ‘each other’ the sentence could mean that every pair of things has a link; with ‘one another’ it could mean only that each thing has a link with **some** other thing.

But where this distinction is intended I would expect it to be worded more explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Thus, since the sentence is about a chain, and with your answer one another is better, isn't it?  continue of the sentence: `These connections come through food and energy. The energy comes from the Sun. Plants use the energy in sunlight to make food.`